# For command with an if then else statement?

Tags: shell, scripting

I want this command to be a condition in which if the file contains the character ^ then rename it or replace it with new name but if it doesn't contain that character ignore this. Thanks!

note: the $f should be the results of f.

```
for f in ./*.png; do mv "$f" "${f%%^*}${f#*^}" ; done
```

EXAMPLE:

ABC4312315_22^_44_25x60.png  --->  ABC4312315_22_44_25x60.png
ABC4312315_22^_22_125x260.png ---> ABC4312315_22_22_125x260.png

Comment: Hi, if you can edit your post and add a few examples on how your filenames are and what is the desired result that may help a lot

Comment: So you want to rename the files that have the caret (^) character or delete them and ignore all other files.  Is that right?  Do you prefer to rename or delete?

Comment: I wasnt clear. i want to go ahead and rename the files with the character ^ and keep the file there. @alariva

Comment: @alariva There you go. :p. sorry i wasnt clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Why loop at all?

**Deleting all files with a `^` in them:**

```
find . -type f -name "*^*.png" -delete
```

**Renaming all files with a `^` in the name to a name without `^` in them:**

```
find . -type f -name "*^*.png" -execdir bash -c 'mv "${1}" "${1//^/}"' -- {} \;
```

---

The last one step by step:

- `find .` -- find in current directory (and subdirectories)...
- `-type f` -- files
- `-name "*^*.png"` -- with name matching the pattern
- `-execdir` -- execute in the directory of the match
- `bash -c '...' -- {}` -- a subshell, taking the name of the match (`{}`) as positional parameter (`$1`)
- `mv "${1}" "${1//^/}"` -- rename `$1` to `$1` with all occurences of `'^'` removed
- `\;` -- end of `exec`'ed command

The subshell is necessary because I have not yet found a way to apply bash parameter expansion on find's `{}` directly. ;-)

[`man find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) -- The swiss army knife for any "operate on a set of files". ;-)

Comment: I'd suggest protecting the glob properly `-name '*^*.png'`. Try creating two filenames (as unlikely as they are): `touch '*^a.png'; touch '*^b.png'`.

Comment: You forgot the backslash there ;)

Comment: @PesaThe: I think we have established you have mastered the proper escaping / protecting way better than me. Where exactly did I forget `'\'`? ;-)

Comment: Haha :) `-name "\*^*.png"` will match only filenames with literal `*` at the beginning. I am guessing you want just simple `-name '*^*.png'`.

Comment: @PesaThe: OK... _more coffee_. That was somewhat embarrasing. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way. Not sure if you were needing more than this. (Notice that I put the extra `echo` in there for demonstration purposes only!)

```
$ touch 'ignore1.png' 'ignore2.png' 'ick^ick.png' '^ick.png' 'ick^.png'
$ for f in ./*^*.png; do echo mv "$f" "${f%%^*}${f#*^}" ; done
mv ./^ick.png ./ick.png
mv ./ick^.png ./ick.png
mv ./ick^ick.png ./ickick.png
$
```

If you needed to not really ignore the other files:

```
$ for f in ./*.png
do
  if [[ "$f" = *'^'* ]]
  then
    echo mv "$f" "${f%%^*}${f#*^}"
  else
    echo "ignoring $f"
  fi
done
mv ./^ick.png ./ick.png
mv ./ick^.png ./ick.png
mv ./ick^ick.png ./ickick.png
ignoring ./ignore1.png
ignoring ./ignore2.png
$
```

Comment: May I ask you why you escape the caret in the `for f in ./*\^*.png` command issued from the command line?

Comment: Yes! Because the '^' character has a hallowed place in matching patterns (It usually means "the start of the string") and so every time I type it in a context where it does NOT have that meaning I automatically put in the '\' in front of it out of habit. I typically take them back out but I missed this one. In this context it doesn't make a difference but I'll take it out for clarity and consistency.

Comment: BTW, if this were a script for my use I'd use '\^' everywhere because it's a reminder to me that it for certain it doesn't mean "start of string" in the current context. I like bludgeoning myself with obviousness.

Comment: But IFIK, the meaning of ^ to indicate the start of a string is only in the context of regular expressions, so this does not apply here. We could argue that the character inside a glob pattern can express the negation of a character set, but for this, it would have to follow a left square bracket, which isn't the case either.

Comment: Correct. It doesn't apply. It also doesn't not apply. It didn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

To **delete** them:

```
for f in *\^*.png; do rm -- "$f"; done
```

For example, make a new directory:

```
$ mkdir a
$ cd a
```

Create some files:

```
$ touch gorp.png bla.png foo.png splut.png jd\^holt.png fo\^o.png gorp\^ers.png \^firsty.png lasty\^.png
```

List them out to confirm they got created:

```
$ ls
```

You should see something like this:

```
$ ls
^firsty.png fo^o.png    gorp.png    jd^holt.png splut.png
bla.png     foo.png     gorp^ers.png    lasty^.png
```

Then delete the ones with the ^ character, like this:

```
$ for f in *\^*.png; do rm -- "$f"; done
```

Confirm they are gone:

```
$ ls
bla.png     foo.png     gorp.png    splut.png
```

Be careful with deleting -- there's no undo. :)

Comment: that `$f` passed to the `rm` should really be quoted. Otherwise it could delete files you didn't intend to.

Comment: It is better to use `rm -- "$f"` just in case a file name were to start with a `-`.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing in your question, there is no need for a loop if you want to delete the files.

`rm -v *\^*.png`

If you insist on using a loop (i.e. you want to do more than just deleting files):

```
for f in ./*.png; do 
  if [[ $string = *"My long"* ]]; then
    mv "$f" "${f%%^*}${f#*^}"
  else
    #something else
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash. First a couple of test files:

```
$ touch yes^this.txt not_this.txt
```

then:

```
$ for f in *this* ; do if [[ "$f" =~ \^ ]] ; then mv "$f" "${f//^/}" ; fi ; done
$ ls *this*
not_this.txt  yesthis.txt
```

Explained:

```
for f in *this*          # loop files with this in file name 
do 
  if [[ "$f" =~ \^ ]]    # bash regex match
  then 
    mv "$f" "${f//^/}"   # bash substring replacement
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in-variable substitution will do:

```
for f in ./*.png; do mv "$f" "${f//^/}" 2>/dev/null ; done
```

I don't bother with the `if` test, because there is no harm in trying to move a file to itself.  I pipe the error output to `/dev/null` because I don't care about it.